# Multiple terminal tabs or windows in WLS Centos

Tags: centos-7, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to open multiple tabs or multiple linux-terminal windows of WSL Centos (7.6) on Windows 10?
I can run two linux instances at once, by opening another one, but I'd like to just have one instance with multiple windows.

[image: Double clicking centos.exe opens two instances]

The reason is that when I run Clion, I can not use the linux-terminal for anything else anymore, as long as Clion is running. I would like to iterate between coding (Clion) and testing the packaged code on the command line.

Interestingly, when I run Eclipse, which like Clion uses Xming, i *can* still use the terminal.

Comment: [Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-preview-v0-7-release/) supports opening multiple tabs.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm confused, i have Centos terminal open, i want to open another terminal or terminal tab to the same Centos instance. How does windows terminal fit in?

Comment: I just opened 2 WSL windows and they both work. Have you tried the same? Did you get any errors?

Comment: You wanted multiple tabs to a terminal window (command prompt).  WSL 2 does not support multiple tabs unless you use Windows Terminal.  It would allow you to have multiple WSL terminal windows.

Comment: If i open 2 WSL windows, do i not run 2 linux instances?

Comment: You aren't opening any instances. You are using a layer built into Windows that translates calls between the Linux services and the Windows Kernel. It is very much the same as opening lots of command prompts.

Comment: @Randomhero we are talking about differentthings: when i opne centos, and then agian open centow by double clicking on centos.exe i get 2 centos instances. So how do i connect to a running centos instance without opening a new one?

Comment: I know what your talking about, and you can start a CentOS bash instance, within a tab of Windows Terminal.   Have you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WSL, when you install, say, Ubuntu, you get one instance of it. Without hacks, you cannot even have multiple instances of the same WSL Linux distribution.

When you open multiple terminals, they “connect” to the same running instance:

[image]

You don’t have to do anything special. Just open multiple terminals and do whatever you want.

The `ubuntu.exe` or `debian.exe` (or whatever) you see is only a client of sorts that connects to the Linux instance that is running in the background. It also starts the instance if it isn’t running yet.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know it was only a client.